# Copiar célula de table ao clicar em button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, table

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e preciso que cada botão copie sua respectiva informação, porém estou tendo problemas com o comando `select()` e `document.execCommand("copy")` como podem ver na imagem, aonde está o meu erro?

```js
  $(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function(){
      var x = $(this).parent().parent().find(':nth-child(1)').html()
      console.log(x);
      x.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
    });
  });
```

[image: erros]

Comment: O erro diz que `x.select` não é uma função revise o código na linha 197 da pagina `revendedor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro que não tem como fazer `.select()` em um código HTML. Você só consegue usar o método `.select()` em elementos de formulário (input, select, textarea etc.)

O erro é porque você está selecionando o HTML (`.html()`) de um elemento e tentando usar o método `.select()` no HTML. O HTML de um elemento não é um elemento, portanto não tem como usar o método. E mesmo que fosse um elemento (que não seja um elemento de formulário, como citado acima), nada irá ocorrer (nada será selecionado ou copiado).

Veja a diferença quando você seleciona e copia o valor de um campo `input`:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function(){
      var x = $(this).parent().parent().find(':nth-child(1)');
      //console.log(x);
      x.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Clique em um botão e dê CTRL+V. Irá colar o mesmo texto do campo:
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" value="código">
      </td>
      <td>
         <button class="btn">Botão</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" value="código2">
      </td>
      <td>
         <button class="btn">Botão</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: então não existe forma de copiar o valor da tabela com o document.execCommand("copy") ?

Comment: Acho que tem um jeito, mas não usando `.select()`. Pode fazer outra pergunta tipo "como copiar o texto de uma célula da tabela", se não houver uma pergunta já feita a respeito.